# How to comment out lines with knitr::spin

Tags: r, knitr

When using `spin` in package `knitr`, how does one simply comment things out to make them invisible to spin?  `roxygen` style lines (`#'`) are taken as lines to appear in the report.  The usual R comment `#` is taken as an `R` comment and appears in a code block.  Lines that are just text, with no special character at the beginning, cause an error.  Lines beginning withe the `LaTeX` comment `%` cause an error.  However, plain lines that follow the start of a chunk are taken to be part of the chunk and appear in the code block (`#+` or `#-`).  So is there a character/symbol that functions to mark a comment line in the true sense of the word?

EDIT: If it has to be invented, the `LaTeX` comment character `%` would be quite handy.  Just saying.

Comment: I guess I did not answer your question completely -- do you want to comment out code lines or normal text lines? I answered the latter. If you want certain code lines to be omitted, you can use `echo=-numbers` as described by Romain below.

Comment: Thanks Yihui.  The functionality I think would be nice (for troubleshooting/convenience) is to be able to block any type of line so that the `spin` parser just simply ignores it.  A single character at the start of the line which can be easily added/removed, in the spirit of universal comments.  If this sounds generally useful I could put it in a feature request.

Comment: Feature request received. Coding now.

Comment: Please test the new feature described below. Thanks! (It is open to suggestions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I added the feature of comments for `spin()` in `knitr` 1.3.2 (see its [Github repos](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) for installation instructions). Now you can

```
#' normal text
#' 

# /* a comment here
runif(10)
# and here */

rnorm(5)
#' text continues
```

---

Old answer:

That depends on the output format. For example, for LaTeX, you use `%`:

```
#' normal text
#' 
#' % a LaTeX comment here
rnorm(5)
#' text continues
```

For HTML, it is `<!-- -->`:

```
#' normal text
#' 
#' <!-- an HTML comment here -->
rnorm(5)
#' text continues
```

Comment: Thank you Yihui, you are very generous with your time.  This is a very helpful feature, and it works as advertised.  Bryan

Answer (score 0):

A long winded solution would be to "echo and eval out" the offending line via the corresponding `echo` and `eval` arguments.

```
#' Regular text

#+ first_chunk, echo = -2, eval = -2
rnorm(10)
runif(20)

#' Text after the chunk
```

Comment: Hmmm... naturally, I was hoping for a solution in which I could select lines of text and prepend the neeeded character... Thank you though.